# datauri/ image to canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

How do I convert an image or datauri to canvas? I see the other way at http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/, but I also want to find out how I can create a canvas at the first place.

The reason I ask this question is because I would like to create a little app that lets user create a canvas 'image', save it as something and be able to reopen it for canvas modification in the future. I figured that datauri is a good way to save a canvas, but I am not sure how I can do to reopen the datauri and use canvas to modify the drawing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an image element using the data URI data as the source and then use drawImage to draw it to the canvas:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = uriData;
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

**Updated**: to clarify that ctx is a 2D context, not a canvas object.

Comment: I did that and it says Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLCanvasElement> has no method 'drawImage'
(anonymous function)

Comment: @DavidT: I've updated the answer to clarify that **ctx** is a 2D context not a top-level Canvas object (which is why you got that error).

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work:

```
var img = new Image();
var uriData = "...."; // replace with dataUri

img.onload = function () {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}

img.src = uriData;
```

Looks like the trick is that the Canvas element needs its width and height specified. When I don't specify the dimensions, it becomes sort of arbitrary and it only shows part of my big image (from dataUri)

Comment: If this is being called multiple times, you probably just want to look up the 2D context once outside the img.onload function.